# Accessing Model From outer-most Directory

Tags: python, django, database, sqlite

I'm attempting to grab a list of blog posts from my Django database. I am able to do it from the view.py within the app, but I would like to reach it from my outer-most directory in order to load sample blog posts on the home page of my website.

I'm guessing there is an easy way to do this I'm missing. There is currently nothing returned to "blogPosts" in this directory. However, when I access it within the "blogPosts" app it returns four tuples.

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from blogPosts.models import BlogPost

def hello_world(request):
    blogPosts = BlogPost.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'home.html')

def videos(request):
    return render(request, 'videos.html')
```

Comment: What do you mean "my outer-most directory". You should not think "directory", you should think "module".

Comment: I guess I mean, the project module? The central module with the name of the project. Sorry, I'm used to C

Comment: You should be able to call it the same way: `from blogPosts.models import BlogPost` as your project should be in the PYTHON_PATH.

Answer (score 0):

My return statement was incorrect.

```
return render(request, 'home.html')
```

Should have included

```
return render(request,'home.html',{'blogPosts':blogPosts})
```